# Accessing a connected device through LAN

Tags: connection, local-area-network, ethernet

I have a metered APC Power Distribution Unit (PDU) which is capable of spewing out the current load, power and such information through a LAN cable. I'm connecting the cable from the PDU to a server node that I have access to. My intention is to get the info that the PDU is sending via HTTP. How do I accomplish that? I assume that the device would take up any IP address within a range, so how do I ping the device without knowing the MAC address (would some kind of trial and error work? I forgot to look it up, and the facility is pretty inaccessible).

In case you are interested to know about the PDU I'm talking about, here is the spec - http://www.apcmedia.com/salestools/ASTE-6Z6KAJ_R0_EN.pdf

I have poor knowledge about networking, so apart from answering to the point which would fix my problem, I would appreciate if you could please elaborate your suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're hooking it straight into the server, you'll need a cross over cable and you'll need to statically configure the IP address of that NIC to be on the same subnet as the PDU.

So if the pdu's IP is 192.168.1.1 with a mask of 255.255.255.0.  Your servers second NIC will need an IP of 192.168.1.2 with a mask of 255.255.255.0.

With that being said, the best way to do it, is plug your PDU into a switch.  Then do the following as detailed in the instuctions on page 13.

APC Device IP Configuration Wizard
You can use the APC Device IP Configuration
Wizard at a computer running Microsoft®
Windows® 2000, Windows 2003, or Windows XP
to configure the basic TCP/IP setting of a Rack
PDU.
1. Insert the APC Metered and Switched Rack
Power Distribution Units Utility CD into a
computer on your network.
2. Launch the Wizard, when prompted, or, if
prompted to restart the computer, access the
Wizard from the Start menu after the
computer has restarted.
3. Wait for the Wizard to discover the
unconfigured PDU, then follow the
on-screen instructions.